# Iif function in SQL Server Report Builder 2012

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

```
=IIf((First(Fields!CustomerCountry.Value, "Invoice"))<>(First(Fields!SupplierCountry.Value, "Invoice"))),0,((Sum(Fields!SellingPrice.Value, "Invoice")*(Parameters!BTW.Value)))
```

I'm making an automatic invoice in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder but I'm stuck on the VAT (BTW-parameter in this example). If a customer is not from the same country as the supplier, he shouldn't pay VAT. If he is, he should pay VAT. I'm thinking i'm missing a parenthese (or having too much of 'em). I'm quite new to SQL so I can't figure it out on my own.

This is the error that pops up: *The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox16.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[1]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error was saying for the `IIF` function it was not able to find the `FalsePart` and it happened due to misplacing of the parentheses (yes you guessed it right).

Code below with correction - not tested though

```
=IIf((First(Fields!CustomerCountry.Value,"Invoice"))<>(First(Fields!SupplierCountry.Value,"Invoice")),0,((Sum(Fields!SellingPrice.Value, "Invoice")*(Parameters!BTW.Value))))
```